# Rorating gear animation in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-animation

I am new in android and I am using android studio

Here is the image.
i want to rotate gears inside this image.
How can i do this? 
Please anybody suggest solution.
[Rotate all three gear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrUem.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create three different ImageViews for each gear. Create a new animation file and copy paste this code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:repeatCount="infinite">

</rotate>
```

Then set the animation to each image view in your on create.